# Make image not-draggable but still clickable/hoverable

Tags: html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I have some images on my site and I would like to know how to stop them from being able to be dragged, but so I can still click/hover on them.

This code does not work on Firefox and I am able to drag it:

```
img {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -moz-user-drag: none;
  -o-user-drag: none;
  user-drag: none;
}
```

This makes it not clickable/hoverable:

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-drag: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the draggable attribute in your img tag

Here's an example:

```
<img
  draggable="false"
  src="#"
/>
```

Comment: @DanielNýdrle I'm on Firefox and it's working for me, maybe you need to explain a bit more on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Well, when I apply the draggable="false" parameter, I am still able to drag the image.  I even tried ondragstart="false;". Do we have the same version (87.0)?

Comment: DanielNýdrle, If you have the CSS still applied from your post on the img tag then it will still be draggable. It works for me on the latest version of Firefox with no CSS

Comment: I see it now, it works only with no CSS. I have already used the JS variant since I do not have to write the draggable="false" for all the images.

Comment: @DanielNýdrle, well I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with JS:

```
window.ondragstart = function() {return false}
```